# Owl carousel как позиционировать по центру экрана

Tags: html, css, api

Я тут макет пытался сверстать. И наткнулся на слайдер. Хотел его сделать с Owl corousel, но не могу понять как к нему стили писать.То есть как с позиционировать его по центру [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока что вот такая хрень.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html - вот пример и еще вот http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/tcyoacpm/

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не отцентрирован div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Его нужно вставить во **wraper**
У которого в свою очередь будет код:

`.wraper {
display: table; //необязательно
width: 980px; //тут твоя ширина контента
margin: 0 auto; //центрирование
}
<div class="wraper"> твой слайдер </div>`